# How do I align my logo and navigation bar to side by side in HTML5 and CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I am new to coding and the whole world of coding and started working on for "fun and education" website to learn, I am stuck, I have a text based logo and a navigation bar, and the both are always on top on of the page which is fine but they are over lapping, how can I align them so they are next to each other and the navigation bar is aligned to centre width of the logo?

```css
h1.one {
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  color: #0066cc;
  font-size: 36px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
}
h1.one a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
h1.one:hover {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
ul.navigation_bar {
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #333;
}
li.navigation_bar {
  float: right;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
p {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}
p br {
  border: 1px solid rgb(12, 27, 232);
}
body {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="one"><a href="index.html"><center>Lorem Ipsum<br>Dolor</br>`</center></a></h1>`
<ul class="navigation_bar">
  <li class="navigation_bar"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navigation_bar"><a href=#blog_posts.html>Blog Posts</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navigation_bar"><a href=#social_media_links.html>Social Media Links</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navigation_bar"><a href=#newsletter.html>Newsletter</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navigation_bar"><a href=#contact.html>Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navigation_bar"><a href=#store.html>Store</a>
  </li>
</ul>


<p>
  <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec molestie sem odio. Nunc molestie auctor mi eu sollicitudin. Sed at tempor justo, a pulvinar ipsum. Nam non placerat neque, non aliquam erat. Proin diam ligula, rhoncus non ex eu, aliquet
  semper sem. Maecenas euismod porttitor augue. Praesent tincidunt nunc ac elit consectetur suscipit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque dictum velit sem, eu congue tortor vulputate
  in.
  </br>

  <br>Mauris consectetur consectetur neque quis varius. Aliquam libero velit, venenatis et erat ac, blandit congue libero. Maecenas aliquam orci ac felis finibus, a eleifend dui tincidunt. Nam justo velit, bibendum nec lobortis a, viverra eget sapien. Nulla
  in porta lorem. Pellentesque eget lorem lacus. Fusce vel sodales sem, eleifend ultrices orci. Nullam ultricies sollicitudin sapien sed viverra. Quisque porta aliquet ante, id convallis felis auctor ac. Vestibulum lobortis nisl congue ultrices eleifend.
  Praesent vehicula quam sit amet bibendum luctus.</br>

  <br>Proin tincidunt varius lacus vitae pellentesque. Aenean a fringilla ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam sed tincidunt nunc. Nunc efficitur scelerisque odio, sit amet elementum mauris hendrerit id. Nulla ac est ut diam facilisis elementum.
  Vivamus et enim iaculis sapien dignissim imperdiet eget quis odio. Pellentesque quam metus, fringilla non sapien ut, hendrerit dictum nulla. Vestibulum porta, arcu at commodo ornare, ante est condimentum lacus, eget vehicula odio ante at arcu. Mauris
  consequat ipsum nibh, non malesuada dolor gravida eu. Etiam justo eros, commodo eu mollis et, commodo sodales nisl. Aliquam consequat ornare ipsum id venenatis. Vivamus vitae est cursus, scelerisque mauris at, tincidunt ipsum. Ut sed ante id erat laoreet
  tincidunt sit amet sit amet dolor.</br>

  <br>Aliquam lacinia volutpat diam, in tincidunt felis tristique egestas. Sed accumsan dolor eget ipsum iaculis hendrerit. Morbi nec sodales libero, non accumsan magna. Mauris at neque odio. Vivamus a mi non risus sollicitudin tincidunt a quis elit. Pellentesque
  vel erat nec diam imperdiet dictum. Integer rhoncus congue mi, vitae pellentesque justo finibus sed. Nulla sit amet erat eros. Vivamus eu pretium lacus. Sed sed blandit neque.</br>

  <br>Vestibulum sit amet nunc elementum nunc semper iaculis. Pellentesque id lacinia massa, non bibendum sem. In aliquam at odio eu pretium. Cras dictum quis lectus quis viverra. Fusce pretium dapibus scelerisque. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent
  per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In efficitur metus quis tortor posuere volutpat. Fusce vel nibh commodo, pellentesque neque nec, aliquet dolor. Aliquam eget libero lacus. Aenean molestie turpis risus, eu sagittis mi interdum vitae. Curabitur
  consequat molestie urna nec rutrum. Pellentesque eget orci sagittis, eleifend dolor non, ultrices enim. Vivamus porttitor feugiat consectetur.</br>
  <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec molestie sem odio. Nunc molestie auctor mi eu sollicitudin. Sed at tempor justo, a pulvinar ipsum. Nam non placerat neque, non aliquam erat. Proin diam ligula, rhoncus non ex eu, aliquet
  semper sem. Maecenas euismod porttitor augue. Praesent tincidunt nunc ac elit consectetur suscipit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque dictum velit sem, eu congue tortor vulputate
  in.
  </br>

  <br>Mauris consectetur consectetur neque quis varius. Aliquam libero velit, venenatis et erat ac, blandit congue libero. Maecenas aliquam orci ac felis finibus, a eleifend dui tincidunt. Nam justo velit, bibendum nec lobortis a, viverra eget sapien. Nulla
  in porta lorem. Pellentesque eget lorem lacus. Fusce vel sodales sem, eleifend ultrices orci. Nullam ultricies sollicitudin sapien sed viverra. Quisque porta aliquet ante, id convallis felis auctor ac. Vestibulum lobortis nisl congue ultrices eleifend.
  Praesent vehicula quam sit amet bibendum luctus.</br>

  <br>Proin tincidunt varius lacus vitae pellentesque. Aenean a fringilla ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam sed tincidunt nunc. Nunc efficitur scelerisque odio, sit amet elementum mauris hendrerit id. Nulla ac est ut diam facilisis elementum.
  Vivamus et enim iaculis sapien dignissim imperdiet eget quis odio. Pellentesque quam metus, fringilla non sapien ut, hendrerit dictum nulla. Vestibulum porta, arcu at commodo ornare, ante est condimentum lacus, eget vehicula odio ante at arcu. Mauris
  consequat ipsum nibh, non malesuada dolor gravida eu. Etiam justo eros, commodo eu mollis et, commodo sodales nisl. Aliquam consequat ornare ipsum id venenatis. Vivamus vitae est cursus, scelerisque mauris at, tincidunt ipsum. Ut sed ante id erat laoreet
  tincidunt sit amet sit amet dolor.</br>

  <br>Aliquam lacinia volutpat diam, in tincidunt felis tristique egestas. Sed accumsan dolor eget ipsum iaculis hendrerit. Morbi nec sodales libero, non accumsan magna. Mauris at neque odio. Vivamus a mi non risus sollicitudin tincidunt a quis elit. Pellentesque
  vel erat nec diam imperdiet dictum. Integer rhoncus congue mi, vitae pellentesque justo finibus sed. Nulla sit amet erat eros. Vivamus eu pretium lacus. Sed sed blandit neque.</br>

  <br>Vestibulum sit amet nunc elementum nunc semper iaculis. Pellentesque id lacinia massa, non bibendum sem. In aliquam at odio eu pretium. Cras dictum quis lectus quis viverra. Fusce pretium dapibus scelerisque. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent
  per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In efficitur metus quis tortor posuere volutpat. Fusce vel nibh commodo, pellentesque neque nec, aliquet dolor. Aliquam eget libero lacus. Aenean molestie turpis risus, eu sagittis mi interdum vitae. Curabitur
  consequat molestie urna nec rutrum. Pellentesque eget orci sagittis, eleifend dolor non, ultrices enim. Vivamus porttitor feugiat consectetur.</br>
  <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec molestie sem odio. Nunc molestie auctor mi eu sollicitudin. Sed at tempor justo, a pulvinar ipsum. Nam non placerat neque, non aliquam erat. Proin diam ligula, rhoncus non ex eu, aliquet
  semper sem. Maecenas euismod porttitor augue. Praesent tincidunt nunc ac elit consectetur suscipit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque dictum velit sem, eu congue tortor vulputate
  in.
  </br>

  <br>Mauris consectetur consectetur neque quis varius. Aliquam libero velit, venenatis et erat ac, blandit congue libero. Maecenas aliquam orci ac felis finibus, a eleifend dui tincidunt. Nam justo velit, bibendum nec lobortis a, viverra eget sapien. Nulla
  in porta lorem. Pellentesque eget lorem lacus. Fusce vel sodales sem, eleifend ultrices orci. Nullam ultricies sollicitudin sapien sed viverra. Quisque porta aliquet ante, id convallis felis auctor ac. Vestibulum lobortis nisl congue ultrices eleifend.
  Praesent vehicula quam sit amet bibendum luctus.</br>

  <br>Proin tincidunt varius lacus vitae pellentesque. Aenean a fringilla ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam sed tincidunt nunc. Nunc efficitur scelerisque odio, sit amet elementum mauris hendrerit id. Nulla ac est ut diam facilisis elementum.
  Vivamus et enim iaculis sapien dignissim imperdiet eget quis odio. Pellentesque quam metus, fringilla non sapien ut, hendrerit dictum nulla. Vestibulum porta, arcu at commodo ornare, ante est condimentum lacus, eget vehicula odio ante at arcu. Mauris
  consequat ipsum nibh, non malesuada dolor gravida eu. Etiam justo eros, commodo eu mollis et, commodo sodales nisl. Aliquam consequat ornare ipsum id venenatis. Vivamus vitae est cursus, scelerisque mauris at, tincidunt ipsum. Ut sed ante id erat laoreet
  tincidunt sit amet sit amet dolor.</br>

  <br>Aliquam lacinia volutpat diam, in tincidunt felis tristique egestas. Sed accumsan dolor eget ipsum iaculis hendrerit. Morbi nec sodales libero, non accumsan magna. Mauris at neque odio. Vivamus a mi non risus sollicitudin tincidunt a quis elit. Pellentesque
  vel erat nec diam imperdiet dictum. Integer rhoncus congue mi, vitae pellentesque justo finibus sed. Nulla sit amet erat eros. Vivamus eu pretium lacus. Sed sed blandit neque.</br>

  <br>Vestibulum sit amet nunc elementum nunc semper iaculis. Pellentesque id lacinia massa, non bibendum sem. In aliquam at odio eu pretium. Cras dictum quis lectus quis viverra. Fusce pretium dapibus scelerisque. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent
  per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In efficitur metus quis tortor posuere volutpat. Fusce vel nibh commodo, pellentesque neque nec, aliquet dolor. Aliquam eget libero lacus. Aenean molestie turpis risus, eu sagittis mi interdum vitae. Curabitur
  consequat molestie urna nec rutrum. Pellentesque eget orci sagittis, eleifend dolor non, ultrices enim. Vivamus porttitor feugiat consectetur.</br>
</p>
```

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated. use CSS `text-align` instead.

Comment: `<center>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used. I'm surprised they are still teaching that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Fixed/Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: @Paulie_D It disturbs me there's no author or contact information specified. Also the website's own HTML doesn't seem all too well-written (considering its HTML5 doctype, HTML5 seems far-far away).

Comment: It's about the basics of layout...it doesn't *need* to be super up to date. The information is clearly explained for new 'developers'...As for contacting the author...why?...but since you ask - http://learnlayout.com/about.html

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/paladi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Instead of using `fixed` position on H1, UL etc...
**use only one fixed element**

```
<div id="fixedHeader">
     <!-- Other elements here (without the fixed thing) -->
</div>
```

```
#fixedHeader{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: I did this and all it dis was mover it to the top. The navigation bar moved to the right and on top but the logo stayed and the text underneath everything so it cannot be seen please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/t3z32px9/1/)

CSS code

```
.menu{
  margin-right: 0px;
  float: right;
 }
  h1.one a{
     text-decoration: none;
     color: white;
   }

  h1.one:hover {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
  }

 ul.navigation_bar {
   list-style-type: none;
   right: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: auto;
   width:80%;
   background-color: #333;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you want to make fixed menu and logo? if you want to make that you can put them in container such  because you use HTML5 or just add div with class and make it fixed.

This is the code  **[Codepin](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGGaPv)**

```css
* {
  text-decoration:none;
  list-style-type:none;
}

nav {
  width:100%;
  height:70px;
  background-color: #2980b9;
  position:fixed;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

h3 > a {
  margin:-10px 8px;
  padding:15px;
  float:left;
  background-color:#34495e;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff
}

ul {
  float:right;
  margin-top:-14px;
  padding-right:60px;
  padding-top:px;
}

ul > li {
  float:right;
  padding:0;
  margin-left:15px;
}

ul > li > a {
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
  padding:20px 4px;
  background-color: #3498db;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:10px;
}

.menu-framework {
  width:100%;
  height:70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="Lorem Ipsum"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Lorem Ipsum"/>
    <meta name="author" content="Magic Liquid" />
    <title>Lorem Ipsum!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/index.css">
</head>
  <body>
   <nav>
      <h3> <a href="#">Site Logo </a> </h3>
        <ul class="navigation_bar">
          <li class="navigation_bar"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="navigation_bar"><a href=#blog_posts.html>Blog Posts</a></li>
          <li class="navigation_bar"><a href=#social_media_links.html>Social Media Links</a></li>
          <li class="navigation_bar"><a href=#newsletter.html>Newsletter</a></li>
          <li class="navigation_bar"><a href=#contact.html>Contact</a></li>
          <li class="navigation_bar"><a href=#store.html>Store</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="menu-framework"></div>
    <p>
        <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec molestie sem odio. Nunc molestie auctor mi eu sollicitudin. Sed at tempor justo, a pulvinar ipsum. Nam non placerat neque, non aliquam erat. Proin diam ligula, rhoncus non ex eu, aliquet semper sem. Maecenas euismod porttitor augue. Praesent tincidunt nunc ac elit consectetur suscipit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque dictum velit sem, eu congue tortor vulputate in.</br>

        <br>Mauris consectetur consectetur neque quis varius. Aliquam libero velit, venenatis et erat ac, blandit congue libero. Maecenas aliquam orci ac felis finibus, a eleifend dui tincidunt. Nam justo velit, bibendum nec lobortis a, viverra eget sapien. Nulla in porta lorem. Pellentesque eget lorem lacus. Fusce vel sodales sem, eleifend ultrices orci. Nullam ultricies sollicitudin sapien sed viverra. Quisque porta aliquet ante, id convallis felis auctor ac. Vestibulum lobortis nisl congue ultrices eleifend. Praesent vehicula quam sit amet bibendum luctus.</br>

        <br>Proin tincidunt varius lacus vitae pellentesque. Aenean a fringilla ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam sed tincidunt nunc. Nunc efficitur scelerisque odio, sit amet elementum mauris hendrerit id. Nulla ac est ut diam facilisis elementum. Vivamus et enim iaculis sapien dignissim imperdiet eget quis odio. Pellentesque quam metus, fringilla non sapien ut, hendrerit dictum nulla. Vestibulum porta, arcu at commodo ornare, ante est condimentum lacus, eget vehicula odio ante at arcu. Mauris consequat ipsum nibh, non malesuada dolor gravida eu. Etiam justo eros, commodo eu mollis et, commodo sodales nisl. Aliquam consequat ornare ipsum id venenatis. Vivamus vitae est cursus, scelerisque mauris at, tincidunt ipsum. Ut sed ante id erat laoreet tincidunt sit amet sit amet dolor.</br>

        <br>Aliquam lacinia volutpat diam, in tincidunt felis tristique egestas. Sed accumsan dolor eget ipsum iaculis hendrerit. Morbi nec sodales libero, non accumsan magna. Mauris at neque odio. Vivamus a mi non risus sollicitudin tincidunt a quis elit. Pellentesque vel erat nec diam imperdiet dictum. Integer rhoncus congue mi, vitae pellentesque justo finibus sed. Nulla sit amet erat eros. Vivamus eu pretium lacus. Sed sed blandit neque.</br>

        <br>Vestibulum sit amet nunc elementum nunc semper iaculis. Pellentesque id lacinia massa, non bibendum sem. In aliquam at odio eu pretium. Cras dictum quis lectus quis viverra. Fusce pretium dapibus scelerisque. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In efficitur metus quis tortor posuere volutpat. Fusce vel nibh commodo, pellentesque neque nec, aliquet dolor. Aliquam eget libero lacus. Aenean molestie turpis risus, eu sagittis mi interdum vitae. Curabitur consequat molestie urna nec rutrum. Pellentesque eget orci sagittis, eleifend dolor non, ultrices enim. Vivamus porttitor feugiat consectetur.</br>      <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec molestie sem odio. Nunc molestie auctor mi eu sollicitudin. Sed at tempor justo, a pulvinar ipsum. Nam non placerat neque, non aliquam erat. Proin diam ligula, rhoncus non ex eu, aliquet semper sem. Maecenas euismod porttitor augue. Praesent tincidunt nunc ac elit consectetur suscipit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque dictum velit sem, eu congue tortor vulputate in.</br>

        <br>Mauris consectetur consectetur neque quis varius. Aliquam libero velit, venenatis et erat ac, blandit congue libero. Maecenas aliquam orci ac felis finibus, a eleifend dui tincidunt. Nam justo velit, bibendum nec lobortis a, viverra eget sapien. Nulla in porta lorem. Pellentesque eget lorem lacus. Fusce vel sodales sem, eleifend ultrices orci. Nullam ultricies sollicitudin sapien sed viverra. Quisque porta aliquet ante, id convallis felis auctor ac. Vestibulum lobortis nisl congue ultrices eleifend. Praesent vehicula quam sit amet bibendum luctus.</br>

        <br>Proin tincidunt varius lacus vitae pellentesque. Aenean a fringilla ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam sed tincidunt nunc. Nunc efficitur scelerisque odio, sit amet elementum mauris hendrerit id. Nulla ac est ut diam facilisis elementum. Vivamus et enim iaculis sapien dignissim imperdiet eget quis odio. Pellentesque quam metus, fringilla non sapien ut, hendrerit dictum nulla. Vestibulum porta, arcu at commodo ornare, ante est condimentum lacus, eget vehicula odio ante at arcu. Mauris consequat ipsum nibh, non malesuada dolor gravida eu. Etiam justo eros, commodo eu mollis et, commodo sodales nisl. Aliquam consequat ornare ipsum id venenatis. Vivamus vitae est cursus, scelerisque mauris at, tincidunt ipsum. Ut sed ante id erat laoreet tincidunt sit amet sit amet dolor.</br>

        <br>Aliquam lacinia volutpat diam, in tincidunt felis tristique egestas. Sed accumsan dolor eget ipsum iaculis hendrerit. Morbi nec sodales libero, non accumsan magna. Mauris at neque odio. Vivamus a mi non risus sollicitudin tincidunt a quis elit. Pellentesque vel erat nec diam imperdiet dictum. Integer rhoncus congue mi, vitae pellentesque justo finibus sed. Nulla sit amet erat eros. Vivamus eu pretium lacus. Sed sed blandit neque.</br>

        <br>Vestibulum sit amet nunc elementum nunc semper iaculis. Pellentesque id lacinia massa, non bibendum sem. In aliquam at odio eu pretium. Cras dictum quis lectus quis viverra. Fusce pretium dapibus scelerisque. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In efficitur metus quis tortor posuere volutpat. Fusce vel nibh commodo, pellentesque neque nec, aliquet dolor. Aliquam eget libero lacus. Aenean molestie turpis risus, eu sagittis mi interdum vitae. Curabitur consequat molestie urna nec rutrum. Pellentesque eget orci sagittis, eleifend dolor non, ultrices enim. Vivamus porttitor feugiat consectetur.</br>      <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec molestie sem odio. Nunc molestie auctor mi eu sollicitudin. Sed at tempor justo, a pulvinar ipsum. Nam non placerat neque, non aliquam erat. Proin diam ligula, rhoncus non ex eu, aliquet semper sem. Maecenas euismod porttitor augue. Praesent tincidunt nunc ac elit consectetur suscipit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque dictum velit sem, eu congue tortor vulputate in.</br>

        <br>Mauris consectetur consectetur neque quis varius. Aliquam libero velit, venenatis et erat ac, blandit congue libero. Maecenas aliquam orci ac felis finibus, a eleifend dui tincidunt. Nam justo velit, bibendum nec lobortis a, viverra eget sapien. Nulla in porta lorem. Pellentesque eget lorem lacus. Fusce vel sodales sem, eleifend ultrices orci. Nullam ultricies sollicitudin sapien sed viverra. Quisque porta aliquet ante, id convallis felis auctor ac. Vestibulum lobortis nisl congue ultrices eleifend. Praesent vehicula quam sit amet bibendum luctus.</br>

        <br>Proin tincidunt varius lacus vitae pellentesque. Aenean a fringilla ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam sed tincidunt nunc. Nunc efficitur scelerisque odio, sit amet elementum mauris hendrerit id. Nulla ac est ut diam facilisis elementum. Vivamus et enim iaculis sapien dignissim imperdiet eget quis odio. Pellentesque quam metus, fringilla non sapien ut, hendrerit dictum nulla. Vestibulum porta, arcu at commodo ornare, ante est condimentum lacus, eget vehicula odio ante at arcu. Mauris consequat ipsum nibh, non malesuada dolor gravida eu. Etiam justo eros, commodo eu mollis et, commodo sodales nisl. Aliquam consequat ornare ipsum id venenatis. Vivamus vitae est cursus, scelerisque mauris at, tincidunt ipsum. Ut sed ante id erat laoreet tincidunt sit amet sit amet dolor.</br>

        <br>Aliquam lacinia volutpat diam, in tincidunt felis tristique egestas. Sed accumsan dolor eget ipsum iaculis hendrerit. Morbi nec sodales libero, non accumsan magna. Mauris at neque odio. Vivamus a mi non risus sollicitudin tincidunt a quis elit. Pellentesque vel erat nec diam imperdiet dictum. Integer rhoncus congue mi, vitae pellentesque justo finibus sed. Nulla sit amet erat eros. Vivamus eu pretium lacus. Sed sed blandit neque.</br>

        <br>Vestibulum sit amet nunc elementum nunc semper iaculis. Pellentesque id lacinia massa, non bibendum sem. In aliquam at odio eu pretium. Cras dictum quis lectus quis viverra. Fusce pretium dapibus scelerisque. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In efficitur metus quis tortor posuere volutpat. Fusce vel nibh commodo, pellentesque neque nec, aliquet dolor. Aliquam eget libero lacus. Aenean molestie turpis risus, eu sagittis mi interdum vitae. Curabitur consequat molestie urna nec rutrum. Pellentesque eget orci sagittis, eleifend dolor non, ultrices enim. Vivamus porttitor feugiat consectetur.</br>
</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**BUT** you will have some issue is your menu will out from his frame and make below content take his place so to avoid this you can make little trick is to put div after the nav and give it a class with some related name like menu-framework and make same menu width and height :

Regards.